# CSS Box Shadow Inset hiding image instead of working as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm Having trouble with Box Shadow inset overlaid on an image, the code snippet below works as expected, however, on my page, the shadow simply hides the image. Here is a screenshot of my issue: [Shadow Overlaying image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOdxU.png)

I know that the image is directly below it because when I adjust the opacity it reveals itself. I'm at a loss for this one, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Code: (works on jsfiddle, but not on my site - see image link above):

```css
.project-img-responsive {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    height: auto;
}

.shadow {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 3px 3px 10px inset;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.column{
 max-width:150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="column">
<div class="shadow">
<img src=" http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="blog" class="project-img-responsive img-circle">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see your implementation that doesn't work?

Comment: I solved my issue. The background was simply overlaying on top of the image, so I found that setting the background to transparent or adjusting the z-index on my background to -2 allows my image to be one layer above it, and thus allowing it to show through and work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it matter the order of the values placed with the box-shadow but I always start with inset then pixels of the inset then color. Try reverse your order maybe it may work. Hope that helps.